# How to use a custom storeId with MVC?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, extjs-stores

Given a store like this, at runtime, the `storeId` will be `App.store.Entities` instead of `Entities`:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Entities', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'Entites',
```

The [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-storeId) states:

> Note that when store is instatiated by Controller, the storeId will be overridden by the name of the store.

This is not only true when the store is required in the controller with

```
stores: ['App.store.Entities'],
```

but also when it is asynchroneously created with

```
this.getStore('App.store.Entities')
```

This is all expected behavior, but I don't like that fact, that this behavior forces the use of either

- the fully qualfied name `App.store.Entities`
- or to stick to that rigid naming convention *and* directory structure.

#### The problem

The problem I have is that my app grows quite large, and having all `store` definitions in one `store` folder is no longer an option. I'd like to refactor to have a folder structure like follows.

```
/app
    /plugin1
        /store
            /Settings
            /Details
        /model
        /view
    /plugin2
        /store
            /Items
            /Settings
        /model
        /view
```

If I could force the `storeId`, I could define it like `'plugin1.Settings'` and would come up with more readable and more portable code than repeating `'App.plugin1.store.Settings'` over the place.

How could I possibly solve this issue ? Where could I go off to start ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I do not let Ext to instantiate my stores (only in rare cases) because that prevents creating multiple instances of the same view class. I instantiate stores manually in views' `initComponent` overrides.

This allows me seamless multiple instances plus I could choose `storeId` if I wished to - I usually don't use storeId but I'm getting stores from views.

However, if you only need to choose storeId because of folder organization, you can use shorter names such as `subfolder1.StoreName1`, etc. but the folder structure must be split inside the `store` folder.

`app/store/subfolder1`
`app/store/subfolder2`

Comment: So are you doing the following?  Feel free to edit answer with a more thorough explanation.  (1) in view1 definition... initComponent: function() { this.store = Ext.Create('App.store.moduleName.storeDefinitionName'); (2) this.callParent(arguments); } ... (3) then in your controller, you get a reference to your view using standard refs, and then say var storeView1 = view1.getStore(); ???  I read that Ed Spensor used to recommend using view.getStore();

Comment: Yes, it's roughly that sequence. It only applies to Ext 4 and below, in Ext 5 I use view models to hold stores.